# Can't Connect Metamask to Ballot Dapp?

Tags: contract-deployment, metamask, dapp-development, testrpc, testrpc-to-ropsten

I want to connect Ballot Dapp to Metamask but it Shows "rpc error with payload" and "ALERT: Trying to call a function on a non-contract address".

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code which shows the error. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yea it seems like there is an error with the way you are calling the function